# getting DOM element coordinates without showing a view in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to get the coordinates of the bounding box for all DOM elements. I am currently using pyqt5 and could do it successfully with the following codes:

```
class Browser(QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Browser, self).__init__()
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._load_finished)

    def _result(self, x):
        for tagname, top, right, bottom, left in x:
            print "%8s %3d %3d %3d %3d"%(tagname, top, right, bottom, left)

    def _load_finished(self):
        js_script = """
                function get_coordinates() {
                    var res = [];
                    var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
                    for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {
                        var rect = all[i].getBoundingClientRect()
                        res.push([all[i].tagName, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom, rect.left]);
                    }
                    return res;            
                }
                get_coordinates();
                """
        self.page().runJavaScript(js_script, self._result)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
br = Browser()
url = QUrl(url_address)
br.load(url)
br.show()
app.exec_()
```

One disadvantage of this codes is that it opens a browser to show the webpage (because of br.show()), and I am wondering if there is any way of preventing this. I simply commented br.show() and ran the codes. But, the coordinate results for some DOM elements are different than the original ones.

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

If you want to not show a window you use `QWebEnginePage`:

```
class Browser(QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Browser, self).__init__()
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._load_finished)

    def _result(self, x):
        for tagname, top, right, bottom, left in x:
            print("%8s %3d %3d %3d %3d"%(tagname, top, right, bottom, left))

    def _load_finished(self):
        js_script = """
                function get_coordinates() {
                    var res = [];
                    var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
                    for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {
                        var rect = all[i].getBoundingClientRect()
                        res.push([all[i].tagName, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom, rect.left]);
                    }
                    return res;            
                }
                get_coordinates();
                """
        self.runJavaScript(js_script, self._result)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
br = Browser()
url = QUrl(url_address)
br.load(url)
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The changed code works fine except one thing. For some DOM elements, I get different coordinates -- only rect.right is different while rect.top, rect.bottom and rect.left are equal. I am trying to figure out why but no luck so far.

Comment: With what measures are you comparing?

Comment: I just compared the return values from the javascript, which uses  getBoundingClientRect to get the coordinates. I tested the codes with a very simple html. 

<html><body><h1 id="test">test</h1></body></html>.

With WebEngineView, h1's bounding box is {left:8, right:792, top: 8, bottom: 45}. With WebEnginePage, h1's bounding box is {left:8, right:8, top: 8, bottom: 45}